# Highlight user selected text in TextField with user selected color

Tags: actionscript-3

I wish to provide simple highlighting feature where a user selects some range of text in a TextField and selects a color and that text's background is highlighted with that color like a marker, its a standard feature on most text editors and word processors. How to achieve this in AS3 (not flex) esp without using html/css in TextField.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution here:
http://tom-lee.blogspot.in/2007/01/textfield-highlighter-class-for-flex.html

Also while hunting for solutions I came accross a generally useful class from Greensock called TextMetrics.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good example of what you want to do:  http://blog.formatlos.de/2009/06/22/as3-texthighlighter/

Comment: Thus it seems there is no straightforward support for highlighting text in Flash platform. I have also found that in Flash CS5 if you select TLF text there is an option to set highlight color of selected text: see [link](http://www.webdesign.org/flash-swish/flash-tutorials/text-layout-framework-in-flash-player-10.19013.html). What is the actionscript counterpart of setting highlight color of selected text programatically using TLFTextField?

Comment: I couldn't find any ActionScript documentation on that "highlight" property.